# How to preserve the "script" tags using .load() method?

Tags: jquery, scripting, load

[`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) will delete all script tags from the load html content(Both in Chrome and Firefox). But I have to use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to refresh part of the web pages and the loaded contents always contain `<script src="xxxxxx"></script>` and `<script>` , which cannot be put to external files. Can anyone give some advice?

Comment: How are you calling `.load()`, are you using a selector or just a URL?

Comment: Using a selector: $("#abcde").load("an url");